# Best practice/starter solution with EF 4 and POCO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, poco

I have been trawling the internet for some months now, looking for some solid (and simple) examples regarding creating a new ASP.NET MVC3 (orMVC2) web site, that could connect to SQL Server 2008, using POCOs and EF4.

I understand the concepts, but seeing as their are many different ways to do the same job i'm struggling to find a full start to finish example I can use as a foundation, for a small web project I want to do in these technologies. I have the luxury of no existing db schema, but do not want to use code-first EF4 approach, I would rather do the model in SQL Server and then import entities into EF4.

I have created a project using 'the full stack' videos, but then realized that is specific to code-first, so sort of scratching my head again now.

If anyone has any good URL's to share, or indeed code/sln files then that would be great. Alternatively, if someone had the spare time to create such a project for a small fee, (50USD), from my specification then I would be interested in that also. I apologies if such requests are not permitted on this forum.

I look forward to hearing your comments.

Comment: is there any particular reason you're shying away from code-first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This music store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-4) uses EF4. Although it's code-first, it shows how to connect to an existing DB as opposed to a lot of tutorials that create the DB "on the fly".

Comment: Thanks for this Paul. I'll take a good look. @Chris - the main reason is how to upgrade the site over time? If I use code-first, the DB model then gets generated. If I upgrade the DB directly, and regenerate the entity model, how does that all fit together. I suppose its more a fear of not knowing how it works, and strugglign to find the documentation. I'm used to deploying the other way around, maintaining schema and code independently etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example on how to "code first" with an existing database schema.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx